# slicing with tf.gather or tf.gather_nd

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a Tensor of size [batch_size x actions_space x N_quantiles]. For the sake of the example, say the dimensions are 2, 3 and 4.

```
x_test = 
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[-0.71722096, -0.36535808, -0.00286232,  0.37722322],
        [ 0.93776643, -1.146626  ,  0.1840729 , -1.427474  ],
        [ 0.47025302, -0.92792755, -0.1490136 ,  1.495174  ]],

       [[-1.3838278 , -0.54772085, -0.14298695,  0.39195213],
        [-0.7986407 ,  0.6419045 , -0.8136323 ,  0.9346474 ],
        [ 0.96690583, -0.82267016, -0.51641494,  0.6930123 ]]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

For each batch, I have a index of an action, and I want to substract the quantile values for this action. So I want to end up having an array of size [Batch_size x N_Quantiles] = [2 x 4].

If my action indices are [2,0], I would thus like to end up with the array:

```
[[ 0.47025302, -0.92792755, -0.1490136 ,  1.495174  ],
[-1.3838278 , -0.54772085, -0.14298695,  0.39195213 ]].
```

How do i fix this with either tf.gather or tf.gather_nd. This should  be dead simple but I am really struggling to extract the correct array. I tried stuff like:

```
tf.gather(x_test, actions, axis=1)
```

But nothing works correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `tf.gather(x_test, actions, batch_dims=1)`

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot. Although, even after considering the docs, I dont exactly understand why haha